# Django Models.py N to N relationship, always says one object is not defined

Tags: django, django-models, foreign-key-relationship, cross-reference

I'm doing a simple test with a Django project with Academies, Teachers and Students.

I'm trying this:

```
class Student(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField()
    direction = models.CharField()
    city = models.CharField()
    telephone = models.CharField(max_length=9)
    email = models.EmailField()
    teachers = models.ForeignKey(Teacher)

class Teacher(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    direction = models.CharField(max_length=150)
    city = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    telephone = models.CharField(max_length=9)
    email = models.EmailField()
    students = models.ForeignKey(Student)

class Academy(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    direction = models.CharField(max_length=150)
    city = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    teacher = models.ForeignKey(Teacher, blank=True, null=True)
    students = models.ForeignKey(Student)
```

The problem is that if I implement first Student, doesnt find theacher to make a Foreign Key, and the same if I implement first Teacher.

There is any way to define the models before implementing them like functions in C?

Thanks!

Comment: Although Aamir's answer is correct, your models don't make any sense. A ForeignKey is a many-to-one relationship, and can't be used to define relationships like "teachers" and "students". However, those are already provided by the *reverse* relationships for the ForeignKeys you have already defined on the teacher and student models.

Comment: @DanielRoseman Yes, I know, was a stupid starting mistake, it has been already fixed.
Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just in `Student` model set Foreign Key to `Teahcer` model as string:

```
teachers = models.ForeignKey('Teacher')
```

As stated [here](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/ref/models/fields/#foreignkey):

> If you need to create a relationship on a model that has not yet been
>   defined, you can use the name of the model, rather than the model
>   object itself

Comment: Just perfect men! Works like a charm and it makes lot more sense than I've done.

Thanks you!